# Kill or timeout a Future in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, timeout, future, scala-2.10

Hi,

I'm using Scala 2.10 with the new futures library and I'm trying to write some code to test an infinite loop. I use a `scala.concurrent.Future` to run the code with the loop in a separate thread. I would then like to wait a little while  to do some testing and then kill off the separate thread/future. I have looked at `Await.result` but that doesn't actually kill the future. Is there any way to timeout or kill the new Scala 2.10 futures?

I would prefer not having to add external dependencies such as Akka just for this simple part.

Comment: No need for Akka - actually, Akka doesn't have futures after 2.1.  Akka's futures moved to `scala.concurrent`.

Comment: relevant, this blog post by Viktor Klang: https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-6.html (not sure the year: 2017? 2018?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not try it at home.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MyCustomExecutionContext extends AnyRef with ExecutionContext {
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  @volatile var lastThread: Option[Thread] = None
  override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = {
    ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.execute(new Runnable() {
      override def run() {
        lastThread = Some(Thread.currentThread)
        runnable.run()
      }
    })
  }
  override def reportFailure(t: Throwable): Unit = ???
}    

implicit val exec = new MyCustomExecutionContext()
val f = future[Int]{ do{}while(true); 1 }
try {
  Await.result(f, 10 seconds) // 100% cpu here
} catch {
  case e: TimeoutException => 
    println("Stopping...")
    exec.lastThread.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("Not started"))
      .stop() // 0% cpu here
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a slightly more elegant solutuion:). It seems to me like this is something you would want to do every so often.

I'll leave the question open for a while longer in the hope someone comes up with something nicer before I accept.

Comment: I would suggest 1) using `while(!terminated)` as in `sourcedelica`'s answer, and 2) create future's closure around `AtomicReference`-s to resources that need to be closed, then close them on completion, and on timeout.

Answer (score 1):

No - you will have to add a flag that your loop checks.  If the flag is set, stop the loop.  Make sure the flag is at least `volatile`.

See [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601), p 135-137.

Comment: The thought of that gives me the willies.

Comment: No worries. Use `interrupt` then `wait` a bit, after than in a case `if (thread.isAlive)` do `connection.close()` and `stop` as a last resort. Customers never complied to me, of being able to actually interrupt a LONG queries in that way =)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and wrote the following nonblocking future op:

```
class TerminationToken(var isTerminated: Boolean)
object TerminationToken { def apply() = new TerminationToken(false) }

 implicit class FutureOps[T](future: Future[Option[T]]) {
 def terminate(timeout: FiniteDuration, token: TerminationToken): Future[Option[T]] = {
   val timeoutFuture = after[Option[T]](timeout, using = context.system.scheduler) {
     Future[Option[T]] { token.isTerminated = true; None } }
          Future.firstCompletedOf[Option[T]](Seq (future recover { case _ => None }, timeoutFuture))
     }
   }
```

Then just create a future that returns an option, and use .terminate(timeout, token) on it