# How to interrupt asynchronous computations in Scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, interrupt-handling

I need to run two parallel computations and interrupt the first one when the second one finishes. Currently, I've implemented it using standard Java threads:

```
/**
 * Runs <var>sup</var> in parallel with <var>main</var>.
 * Terminate (interrupt) it when <var>main</var> finishes.
 */
def support[R](sup: => Unit, main: => R): R = {
  val supThread = new Thread {
    override def run = { sup };
  }

  supThread.start();
  try {
    main;
  } finally {
    supThread.interrupt();
  }
}
```

Can the same behavior be achieved using Scala's concurrent library, without using `Thread`s explicitly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449862/kill-or-timeout-a-future-in-scala-2-10/14450095#14450095

Comment: Your implementation with Java's API is not reliable - interrupt doesn't always work as expected and should probably never be used. It's better to code explicitly for early termination - e.g. as in the answer linked in the comment above. Sharing an AtomicBoolean is one of the (many) possible solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Not with Scala standard futures (AFAIK), but [Twitter's Util library](https://github.com/twitter/util) does support it:

```
val future = Future { sup }
future.cancel() // in 5.x
future.raise(new FutureCancelledException) // in 6.x
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent to this in the Scala standard library now, 2 years on to your knowledge?

Comment: Not directly, but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16010193/9204 and especially the discussion in the comments.

Comment: You can achieve this using Promises in Scala.