# Cancellation with Future and Promise in Scala

Tags: scala, promise, akka, future, cancellation

This is a followup to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala).

Suppose I have a task, which executes an *interruptible* blocking call. I would like to run it as a `Future` and *cancel* it with `failure` method of `Promise`.

I would like the *cancel* to work as follows:

- If one *cancels* the task *before* it finished I would like the task to finish "immediately", interrupting the blocking call if it has already started and I would like the `Future` to invoke `onFailure`.
- If one *cancels* the task *after* the task finished I would like to get a status saying that the cancel failed since the task already finished.

Does it make sense? Is it possible to implement in Scala? Are there any examples of such implementations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

scala.concurrent.Future is read-only, so one reader cannot mess things up for the other readers.

It seems like you should be able to implement what you want as follows:

```
def cancellableFuture[T](fun: Future[T] => T)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext): (Future[T], () => Boolean) = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  val f = p.future
  p tryCompleteWith Future(fun(f))
  (f, () => p.tryFailure(new CancellationException))
}

val (f, cancel) = cancellableFuture( future => {
  while(!future.isCompleted) continueCalculation // isCompleted acts as our interrupted-flag

  result  // when we're done, return some result
})

val wasCancelled = cancel() // cancels the Future (sets its result to be a CancellationException conditionally)
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I execute some _interruptible_ blocking call instead of calculation. How can I modify the code above to interrupt the thread?

Comment: You'd have to add a synchronized var that sets the current thread under a lock when the computation starts, and then takes the lock at the end and clears the var. And the cancel would take the lock and call interrupt on the set Thread, if any, or bail out if null.

Comment: should it be `while(!future.isCompleted && moreWork) continueCalculation`?

Comment: Cool - I figured but i was coding it up as an exercise and wanted to be sure :)  The future that is passed into `fun` as a flag, is there anything special about it being a future other than it is read only and atomic?  For example, could you use an AtomicBoolean instead (except it is read/write)?

Comment: sourcedelica: An AtomicBoolean is mutable so that might not be the best choice, the reason for the Future is that it's already allocated and doesn't interfere in any way.

Comment: Hi @ViktorKlang, is it possible the future in the output on cancellable is not the interesting one? I mean did you mean `val f = Future(fun(p.future)) ;
  p tryCompleteWith f`

Comment: @FranciscoLópez-Sancho I'm not sure I understand what you mean—could you clarify a bit?

Comment: Sorry @ViktorKlang, of course. I kind of feel that the future one wants back from the `cancellabeFuture` is not the future from the promise `val f = p.future` as this future is only used to trigger the cancellation. From inside `cancellableFuture`. on `while(!future.isCompleted) continueCalculation`. This future is essential to stop the calculation but the calculation itself is wrapped in other future `p tryCompleteWith Future(fun(f))`. And this `Future(fun(f))` is the one that we may want to get out of the method `cancellableFuture` maybe to add a callback to or something else?

Comment: @FranciscoLópez-Sancho In the code, the Future returned will contain the result of the computation, or a CancellationException.

Comment: awesome! :) Thank you for letting me know @ViktorKlang

Comment: @FranciscoLópez-Sancho you're most welcome—I'm happy that so many developers use Future & Promise. :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is the interruptable version of Victor's code per his comments (Victor, please correct me if I misinterpreted).

```
object CancellableFuture extends App {

  def interruptableFuture[T](fun: () => T)(implicit ex: ExecutionContext): (Future[T], () => Boolean) = {
    val p = Promise[T]()
    val f = p.future
    val aref = new AtomicReference[Thread](null)
    p tryCompleteWith Future {
      val thread = Thread.currentThread
      aref.synchronized { aref.set(thread) }
      try fun() finally {
        val wasInterrupted = (aref.synchronized { aref getAndSet null }) ne thread
        //Deal with interrupted flag of this thread in desired
      }
    }

    (f, () => {
      aref.synchronized { Option(aref getAndSet null) foreach { _.interrupt() } }
      p.tryFailure(new CancellationException)
    })
  }

  val (f, cancel) = interruptableFuture[Int] { () =>
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(1)

    latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)    // Blocks for 5 sec, is interruptable
    println("latch timed out")

    42  // Completed
  }

  f.onFailure { case ex => println(ex.getClass) }
  f.onSuccess { case i => println(i) }

  Thread.sleep(6000)   // Set to less than 5000 to cancel

  val wasCancelled = cancel()

  println("wasCancelled: " + wasCancelled)
}
```

With `Thread.sleep(6000)` the output is:

```
latch timed out
42
wasCancelled: false
```

With `Thread.sleep(1000)` the output is:

```
wasCancelled: true
class java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
```

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely cleaner.

Comment: Updated per Victor's gist.

Comment: Why isn't the answer by @ViktorKlang updated to reflect his own comments and the gist?! It appears two answers compete with each other while there's a single author :(

Comment: They are two different variations, they don't compete with each other.  Viktor's uses a `cancel()` method to cancel the operation and mine uses `Thread.interrupt`.

Answer (score 6):

Twitter's futures implement cancellation. Have a look here:

https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Future.scala

Line 563 shows the abstract method responsible for this. Scala's futures currently do not support cancellation.

Comment: Does it still? You linked to master, so the code has shifted since then.

Comment: Oh dear... It seems that `raise` might have replaced this functionality: https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Future.html#raise(interrupt:Throwable):Unit

Answer (score 2):

You can use Monix library instead of Future

https://monix.io