# Cancelling Long Running Web-services in Play

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I'm using Play2 (with Java) to write a webservice which runs a fairly computationally expensive operation.  As per the documentation, I've broken up the process into a chain of promises resembling:

```
// Do some IO stuff on a background thread
Promise<ExtractionResult> extractDataPromise = Akka.future(new Callable<ExtractionResult>(){
    @Override
    public ExtractionResult call() throws Exception {

        return null;
    }
});

// Perform a couple computations based on the result
Promise<MyResult> longRunningComputation1 = extractDataPromise.map(
    new Function<ExtractionResult, MyResult>(){
        public MyResult apply(ExtractionResult er){
            return longRunningComputation();
        }
    }
)

Promise<MyResult> longRunningComputation2 = extractDataPromise.map(
    new Function<ExtractionResult, Result>(){
        public Result apply(ExtractionResult er){
            return longRunningComputation();
        }
    }
)

// Synchronize back up to make the result
Promise.sequence(longRunningComputation1, longRunningComputation2).flatMap(
    // Do something with the results
)
```

From what I've read in the documentation, you cannot inturrupt an actor in the middle of its execution, that is, I could not cancel the chain above in the middle of performning the IO or in the middle of the longRunningComputation.  Would it be possible to cancel the entire operation *between* the chained calls?  That is, if the user made a cancel request, could I set a flag that the operations could check to essentially become no-ops and return a null result?  Is there another recommended way to cancel long-running service requests?

I'm fairly new to both Play and the underlying Akka framework, so I'm open to suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: You can try to implement some sort of cancellable Future and return it from the actor. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020964/cancellation-with-future-and-promise-in-scala (scala).

Comment: That's basically exactly what I ended up doing.  Thanks