# Can I stop a Play Framework promise?

Tags: scala, playframework, promise, future

Is there an advisable way to stop a Play Framework promise? For instance,

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise

val timeoutFuture = Promise.timeout({
    Logger.info("timeout expired.")
}, myTimeoutValue)
```

What would be a good way to cancel this future before `myTimeoutValue` expires?

Comment: Hint in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I'm afraid the answer was no - there was no way of cancelling such promise before the timeout expires.

Answer (score 1):

If the timeout period is too long just reduce the `myTimeoutValue`. If you wish to interrupt the execution the is a way [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020964/cancellation-with-future-and-promise-in-scala) by completing a future.

This is however questionable way to do things since you can just ignore the result of your Promise/Future if it takes too long, but since you'll have to set a period for when its too long then its just as well as putting that as the timeout value.