# Scala and Java interop. of Future

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10, scala-java-interop

In this problem I have to call a third-party Java library that expects a `java.util.concurrent.Future` with a result from a Scala routine returning a `scala.concurrent.Future` as for example.

```
def someScalaFunction(): scala.concurrent.Future[T]

def otherJavaMethod(arg: java.util.concurrent.Future[T]) = ...
```

I would wrap the Scala-Future into a new Java-Future, however there is no way to implement the Java-Future method `def cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean` in a way it interrupts the wrapped Scala-Future (if otherwise please let me know).

How can I solve this problem? These are the approaches I come up with:

1. write the wrapper anyway and just ignore the call on `cancel` (or throw an `NotImplementedError`)
2. change `someScalaFunction` to maybe return a closure that will then be wrapped by the caller in a Scala or Java Future.

The problem with 1. is that some client could rely on the proper implementation of `cancel` but is maybe not very critical. 
2. would result in a really ugly api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `cancel` only attempts to cancel the task, there are no guarantees according to the Javadoc. So you don't really have to implement it to do something -- depending on what the future computation is, ignoring the `cancel` call may not be subsequential for the entire application.

If you really need to cancel it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala/16010193) for a half-solution.

Otherwise, you could use your second solution -- with the help of some implicit conversions  you could make it look nicer.

```
object JavaInterOp {
  implicit def f2future[F[_]](f: () => T): java.util.concurrent.Future[T] = fc(f)
}
```

This way, the import controls which conversion you want to provide and when.

One issue with this is that it might do the conversion where you don't really want it -- it might yield surprising effects.