# Execute competing calculations in parallel and discard all but the first one that finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I wrote a function that generates a labyrinth based on randomness. Most of the time, this function is very fast. But every once in a while, due to bad luck with the random numbers, it takes a couple of seconds.

I would like to start this function multiple times in parallel and let the fastest function "win".

Does the Scala standard library (or the Java standard library) provide a fitting tool for this job?

Comment: It might be easier (and more efficient) to find out why the program sometimes takes a couple of seconds and fix it...

Comment: you may want [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), but i agree with @immibis

Comment: @immibis It seems labyrinth generation (with no dead ends) is just a hard problem, and every solution I have found/can think of requires heavy backtracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 years later, I stumbled upon `ExecutorService.invokeAny`, which does exactly what I want:

> Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception), if any do (before the given timeout elapses).
>
> Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.

```java
<T> T invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException;

<T> T invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks,
                long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException;
```

Implementation sketch:

```
class LabyrinthGenerator implements Callable<Labyrinth> {
    private static final int N = 16;
    private static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);

    public static Labyrinth generate() {
        while (true) {
            List<LabyrinthGenerator> generators = Stream.generate(LabyrinthGenerator::new)
                                                        .limit(N)
                                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            try {
                return pool.invokeAny(generators, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException ex) {
                // all attempts failed or timed out, try again
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Labyrinth call() throws Exception {
        // ...
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // some other generator found a result, abort
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the other 3 tasks will still keep running until they finish.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Future`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val futures = for (_ <- 1 to 4) yield Future { /* computation */ }
val resultFuture = Future.firstCompletedOf(futures)
```

If you want to block (I presume you do), you can use `Await.result`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

val result = Await.result(resultFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to cancel the pending calculations when the first calculation finishes?

Comment: @FredOverflow see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala

Answer (score 2):

A java 8 solution with `CompletableFuture`:

```
public class FirstDoneWithCompletableFutureEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        int jobs = 10;
        CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = new CompletableFuture[jobs];
        for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
            futures[i] = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                //computation    
                return new Object();
            });
        }

        //first job done
        Object firstDone = CompletableFuture.anyOf(futures).get();
    }
}
```

A java 5,6,7 solution with `CompletionService`:

```
public class FirstDoneWithCompletionServiceEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        int jobs = 10;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(jobs);
        CompletionService<Object> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);

        for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++)
            completionService.submit(
                    new Callable<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public Object call() throws Exception {
                            //computation
                            return new Object();
                        }
                    }
            );

        //get first job done
        Object firstDone = completionService.take().get();

        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect chance to use CompletableFuture with an acceptEither CompletionStage.