# Convert scala future to java future

Tags: java, scala, akka, future, scala-java-interop

I have a generated java interface containing a method:

```
public Future<?> getCustomersAsync(AsyncHandler<Customer> asyncHandler);
```

I want to implement it using Akka. I wrote following:

```
override def getCustomerAsync(asyncHandler: AsyncHandler[Customer]): Future[_] = {
  myActorRef.ask(GetCustomer, system.actorOf(Props[Responder]))
}
```

The issue is that `ask` returns `scala.concurrent.Future[Any]` and the method must return `java.util.concurrent.Future[?]`:

```
Error:(33, 17) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Any]
 required: java.util.concurrent.Future[?]
    myActorRef.ask(GetCustomer, system.actorOf(Props[Responder]))
                  ^
```

How can I do this conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well its not practical to convert them, because scala `Future` do not provide functionality to interrupt or any other mechanism for cancellation. So there is no direct **full-proof** way to cancel a future via interruption or otherwise via method call in Future.

So the simplest solution can be if cancellation is not desired would be:

```
  def convert[T](x:Future[T]):java.util.concurrent.Future[T]={
    new concurrent.Future[T] {
      override def isCancelled: Boolean = throw new UnsupportedOperationException

      override def get(): T = Await.result(x, Duration.Inf)

      override def get(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit): T = Await.result(x, Duration.create(timeout, unit))

      override def cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean): Boolean = throw new UnsupportedOperationException

      override def isDone: Boolean = x.isCompleted
    }
  }
```

But in case if you still need `cancel`, a handicapped fix would be as shown

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala/16010193). But I wouldn't recommend it though as its shaky

Answer (score 7):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library includes [`scala.jdk.FutureConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/FutureConverters$.html) which provides Scala to Java `Future` conversions (and vice versa):

```
import scala.jdk.FutureConverters._

// val scalaFuture: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future.successful(42)
scalaFuture.asJava
// java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[Int] = <function1>
```

---

Note for Java users, you'd rather use `FutureConverters` the explicit way:

```
import scala.jdk.javaapi.FutureConverters;

// val scalaFuture: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future.successful(42)
FutureConverters.asJava(scalaFuture);
// java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage[Int] = <function1>
```

Comment: Could you please include the information how the converted future handles the cancellation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a easy way to convert scala Future to java Future. One possible solution is to wrap scala future by java future but you must pass a new task to the thread pool, see java docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html