# implement onComplete Scala Future in Kotlin

Tags: scala, kotlin

I´m invoking from Kotlin a Scala class that return a Future, I can make an Await of that future

```
private fun scalaFutureInKotlin() {
    val future: Future<String> = Future.successful("Hello world from Scala")
    val result: String? = Await.result(future, Duration.apply(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    println(result)
}
```

But what I really want is to being able to implement the `onComplete` callback and pass the value into a Kotlin `Channel` or `Flow` to being used in another `coroutine`, so then I dont block any thread.

Any idea how to implement a `onComplete` function of a `Scala Future` in `Kotlin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55466092/11377112):

> Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library includes [`scala.jdk.FutureConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/jdk/FutureConverters$.html) which provides Scala to Java `Future` conversions (and vice versa):
>
> ```scala
> import scala.jdk.javaapi.FutureConverters
> import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage
>
> val javaFuture: CompletionStage<Int> = FutureConverters.asJava(scalaFuture)
> ```

Once you get [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html), you can interop with it in Kotlin with following options:

1. As [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) offers [CompletionStage.await](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) function defined on that so you can asynchronously wait for the completion of the future:

```kotlin
// Dependencies:
// implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9"
// implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.3.9"
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.*
import java.util.concurrent.*
import scala.jdk.javaapi.FutureConverters

private suspend fun scalaFutureInKotlin() {
    val future: Future<String> = Future.successful("Hello world from Scala")
    val javaFuture: CompletionStage<Int> = FutureConverters.asJava(future)
    val result: String? = javaFuture.await()  // asynchronous await, function resumes when result is available, callable by suspend function only
    println(result)
}

// Examples:
suspend fun main() {
    scalaFutureInKotlin()
}

// or for calling from coroutine when not inside suspendable block
fun main() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    scope.launch { scalaFutureInKotlin() }  // call from inside coroutine
}
```

2. Directly add listeners to CompletionStage:

```kotlin
import java.util.concurrent.*
import scala.jdk.javaapi.FutureConverters

private fun scalaFutureInKotlin() {
    val future: Future<String> = Future.successful("Hello world from Scala")
    val javaFuture: CompletionStage<Int> = FutureConverters.asJava(future)
    javaFuture.thenAccept { result ->  // use thenApply if you want to return sth and chain the calls
        println(result)
    }
}
```