# Compose futures by Scala Async

Tags: scala, concurrency, async-await

There are futures f1, f2 and f3. If we need wait till both f1 `and` f2 complete `or` f3 does, i.e. the condition looks like `completed(f1) & completed(f2) | completed(f3)`, how can we use [Scala Async](https://github.com/scala/async) to compose it fluently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know async, but you could probably find a solution using [Future.firstCompletedOf](http://semberal.github.io/scala-future-timeout-patterns.html) and [promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html). There's already a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala) on SO about this.

If you don't care about cancelling the futures, you can simply do something like :

```
val f1 = Future { /*...*/ }
val f2 = Future { /*...*/ }
val f3 = Future { /*...*/ }

Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(f1.flatMap(f2), f3))
```