# Cancel a Future after stopping an actor

Tags: scala, akka, future, actor

I have an application with Master-Worker architecture. The Worker needs to do a heavy and long time job. And the Master needs to kill the job when we need.

I've tried not to use `Future` and the worker cannot receive any message while working. So I tried to use `Future` instead. However, when the Worker was stopped, job was still running. How can I release the resources after stopping the actor?

Here is the code.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Terminated}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._


object Main extends App {

  object StopTask

  case class DoTask(task: String)

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem")
    val master = system.actorOf(Props[Master], "master")
    master ! "FooTask"
    import system.dispatcher
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5 second) {
      master ! StopTask
    }
  }

  class Master extends Actor {
    val worker: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[Worker], "worker")

    def receive: Receive = {
      case task: String => worker ! DoTask(task)
      case StopTask => context stop worker
    }
  }

  class Worker extends Actor {

    import context.dispatcher

    override def postStop(): Unit = {
      println("Stopping task...")
    }

    def receive: Receive = {
      case DoTask(task) =>
        Future {
          // High loading job here
          while (true) {
            println(s"Doing $task...")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
          }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

The output is...

```
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:33,947 akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:34,244 akka.remote.Remoting - Starting remoting
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:34,463 akka.remote.Remoting - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:49770]
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:34,466 akka.remote.Remoting - Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:49770]
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:34,521 akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem) - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:49770] - Starting up...
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:34,717 akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem) - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:49770] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster,port=49770]
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:34,718 akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem) - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:49770] - Started up successfully
Doing FooTask...
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:34,777 akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem) - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:49770] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[INFO ] 2018-04-08 21:48:35,017 akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://ClusterSystem) - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:49770] - Welcome from [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2560]
Doing FooTask...
Doing FooTask...
Doing FooTask...
Doing FooTask...
Stopping task...
Doing FooTask...
Doing FooTask...
```

I have found [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala) to kill `Future`. But I don't know how to integrate into this architecture. Hope anyone to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my original answer (breaking up a Future's execution by recursively chaining it with itself) didn't really solve the problem, I did a little research and saw this idea from Dr Roland Kuhn: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/nkD5BN17kVk/RpUbm07rvpMJ

> ... you can also spawn a dedicated thread for running that and have an actor manage it; in this case you can call Thread.interrupt or Thread.stop any way you like while keeping the actor responsive.

I played around with this idea of having an actor manage starting and stopping a thread. Since actors are a good way to manage potentially-expensive resources, an actor is indeed a good candidate to manage a thread. Here's my implementation:

```
/** Does the main work (i.e. training ML model). */
class WorkerThread(task: String, parent: ActorRef) extends Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = try {
    while (true) {
      println(s"Doing $task...")
      Thread sleep 500
    }
  } catch {
    /* Since this thread may be interrupted at any time, we need to
       gracefully handle being interrupted. Since we have a handle to the
       actor that's managing us, we can send it a message telling it to
       finish up. */
    case _: InterruptedException => parent ! Worker.Message.FinishUp
  }
}

/** Manages starting and stopping the model training thread. */
class Worker extends Actor {
  private var thread: Thread = null

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Worker.Message.DoTask(task) =>
      if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(new WorkerThread(task, self))
        thread.start()
      }
    case Worker.Message.StopTask =>
      if (thread != null) thread.interrupt()
    case Worker.Message.FinishUp => println("Stopped task...")
  }
}

object Worker {
  sealed trait Message
  object Message {
    case class DoTask(task: String) extends Message
    case object StopTask extends Message
    case object FinishUp extends Message
  }
}
```

Now, we can stop the ML model training at any time using its managing actor. It turns out a Future was the wrong level of abstraction to use, but a Thread is the right one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the infinite loop is just the example. Actually I need to run a long time job in that block such as training machine learning model. So I cannot use the chain method. Is there any way to kill the future and release its resources?

Comment: Is there any way to cancel the training of the machine learning model?

Comment: @ShyuKevin redid my answer.