# interrupt scala parallel collection

Tags: scala, fork-join, parallel-collections

Is there any way to interrupt a parallel collection computation in Scala?

Example:

```scala
val r = new Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    (1 to 3).par.foreach { _ => Thread.sleep(5000000) }
  }
}
val t = new Thread(r)
t.start()
Thread.sleep(300) // let them spin up
t.interrupt()
```

I'd expect `t.interrupt` to interrupt all threads spawned by `par`, but this is not happening, it keeps spinning inside `ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone`. Looks like that method clears the interrupted status and keeps waiting for the spawned threads to finish.

This is Scala 2.12

Answer (score 2):

The thread that you `t.start()` is responsible just for starting parallel computations and to wait and gather the result.

It is not connected to threads that compute operations. Usually, it runs on default `forkJoinPool` that independent from the thread that submits computation tasks.

If you want to interrupt the computation, you can use custom execution back-end (like manually created `forkJoinPool` or a `threadPool`), and then shut it down. You can read about that [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html).

Or you can provide a callback from the computation.

But all those approaches are not so good for such a case.

If you producing a production solution or your case is complex and critical for the app, you probably should use something that has cancellation by design. Like `Monix.Task` or `CancellableFuture`.

Or at least use `Future` and cancel it with [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala).

Comment: I know how to work this around, there are many ways. But that's a lot of boilerplate to implement the behavior that should be there from the start IMO. I don't see any logic behind `t.interrupt()` being a no-op. I'd be using `ForkJoinTask.get()`, not `.join()` in `WrappedTask.sync` and handle interruptions correctly.