# How to kill all threads caused by Scala .par when one throws and exception?

Tags: multithreading, scala

This code blocks, the exceptions that are thrown don't kill the loop

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).par.foreach { i =>
        println("i = " + i)

        if (i == 5) {
          println("Sleeping forever")
          java.lang.Thread.sleep(Long.MaxValue)
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("foo")
      } must throwA[IllegalArgumentException]
```

Is there a way to use `.par` but make it blow up properly?

Comment: I would just use plain `Futures` and `traverse` instead of `par`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Worked like a charm.  Post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to work, but verbose though

```
implicit class PimpedListScala[T](l: List[T]) {
    def parForeachThrowOnException(f: T => Unit, sleepMillis: Long): Unit = {
      var exception: Option[Throwable] = None

      val future = Future(
        l.par.foreach(e =>
          try {
            f(e)
          } catch {
            case t: Throwable =>
              if (exception.isEmpty) exception = Some(t)
          }
        )
      )

      while (exception.isEmpty && !future.isCompleted) {
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(sleepMillis)
      }

      exception.foreach(throw _)
    }
  }
```

I've also tried this

```
def parForeachThrowOnException(f: T => Unit): Unit =
      Await.result(Future.traverse(l)(a => Future(f(a))), Duration.Inf)
```

but this works unpredictably.  For a live experiment it took a full 2 hours for the first exception thrown to propagate up and kill the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when using the par libs you should expect the exception to occour once all the threads actually finish and are are joined back into the current thread, I suspect this because by looking at the implementation of the foreach method (cmd clicking on foreach) a method named executeAndWaitResult is used

Here are some other q/s that seem somewhat similar perhaps it helps
[interrupt scala parallel collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291722/interrupt-scala-parallel-collection)
[How to cancel Future in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009837/how-to-cancel-future-in-scala)

https://immutables.pl/2016/10/08/parallel-futures-and-exceptions/